# Im using richTextBox to view log but how do i make it not ot move down to a new line each time?

Tags: c#

This is how im using it in the timer tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memUsage = theMemCounter.NextValue();
            label1.Text = memUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Memory Usage   " + memUsage.ToString());
            AppendText(richTextBox1, "Memory Usage   " + memUsage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine, Color.Red);
            cpuUsage = this.theCPUCounter.NextValue();
            label2.Text = cpuUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Cpu Usage   " + this.cpuUsage.ToString());
            AppendText(richTextBox1, "Cpu Usage   " + cpuUsage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine, Color.Blue);
            Values.Add(cpuUsage);
            isProcessRunning();
            if (alreadyRun == true)
            {
                processValues.Add(cpuUsage);
            }

        }
```

This is the AppendText function:

```
public  void AppendText( RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }
```

If in the timer tick i will not use the Environment.NewLine then i will see only one of the only the memory usage one line repeating it self.

If im using the Environment.NewLine then i see the memory Usage and the cpu Usage down to a new line each time for example:

Moemory usage --- 3
Cpu usage --- 0.4565
Memory usage --- 3.6
Cpu usage --- 47

Instead i want to see one line of the memory usage and one line of the cpu uage and to update this two lines over and over and not to make a new lines for them.

Comment: Why do you use then RichtextBox?

Comment: L.B that way i can color the lines the text. What should i use then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to only have 2 lines that are updated, try the following:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = "";
    // Add the rest of the code here
}
```

That way it will display 2 lines (memory and cpu usage) and after a tick, it will clear the text and then set those 2 lines. This will appear as if it is updating.

Hope this helps!